# variable names in function definition, call and declaration

Tags: function, declaration, definition

I see C books that use the same variable names in the function definition, calling function and declaration. Others use the same variable names in the calling function and in the declaration/prototype but a different one in the definition as in:

```
void blabla(int something); //prototype

blabla(something)  // calling function inside main after something has been initialized to int 

void blabla(int something_else)  //definition
```

I have two questions:

1. What convention is best to use in C?;
2. Does the convention apply regardless whether a value is being passed "by-value" or if it's being passed by a pointer?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name used for a function parameter in a function declaration is basically just a comment.  It doesn't have any meaning and (as you've noticed) doesn't have to match the function definition.  That said, it should be a good descriptive name that tells you what the parameter is for.  So why not use the same name in the declaration?  If you use a different name and one of the names is better (more descriptive), then you should probably use that name in both places.

Comment: Thanks. So basically it's good to use a single descriptive name which will go equally well in the declaration, calling function and definition. No need to invent other different variable names?

Comment: Given two names, either one of them is clearly better than the other - in which case you would do well by using the better one in both places - or both are equally meaningless ;) - in which case you should choose one and stick to it if only for the sake of consistency.

Comment: So it's best to have the same name in the declaration and in the definition. And then we can put another names in the calling function.